# Fix #REF! "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data" without having to remove data

Tags: google-sheets

Wonder is there a way to fix the aforementioned #REF! without having to remove data in the cell that blocks the expansion. I used INDEX, MATCH, HLOOKUP and IMPORTRANGE in the formula, [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hax7E.png) to see the full formula.

Comment: No screenshots of code please.

Comment: should try using array_constrain, and constrain the result by col and rows.

Answer (score 0):

the only way is to not use arrayed output but to have formula in each cell. looking at your formula you cant use `A3:B7`